# Unity: How to draw GUI texture under UI elements?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

In Unity: How can I draw GUI texture (GUI.DrawTexture) on my 2D application and at the same time have some UI buttons to appear over the drawn GUI and also to be able to interact with these buttons?

Comment: Why would you use `GUI.DrawTexture` instead of the `Image` or `RawImage` component?

Comment: I use GUI.DrawTexture to draw lines on Image (best solution I found)

Comment: LineRenderer....That's what you use to draw lines.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't get what i want from it (LineRenderer is drawn under all UI elements which is the opposite of GUI.DrawTexture )

Answer (score 2):

Use Unity's `LineRenderer` and `Image` or `RawImage` because `GUI.DrawTexture` is from IMGUI and should only be used to make Editor plugins or tools.

> I tried it but it didn't get what i want from it (LineRenderer is
>   drawn under all UI elements which is the opposite of GUI.DrawTexture )

The problem is how you setup the Canvas. The default Canvas Render Mode is *"Screen Space - Overlay"*. When the Canvas is set to *"Screen Space - Overlay"*, it will display on top of everything.

Change your Canvas Render Mode to *"Screen Space - Camera"* then add your main camera to the Canvas' *"Render Camera"* slot. You can also use *"World Space"* as Render Mode. `LineRenderer`  should now display on top of the Canvas.

Comment: That's did what you say. But the problem is here. The Lines is drawn over all buttons and panels.
I just want it to be drawn over a gameobject (image), and under buttons.

Comment: Did you actually read my answer? I told you to change the Canvas Render Mode to *"Screen Space - Overlay"* and plug the main camera to the *"Render Camera"* slot and the LineRenderer will be drawn on top of the Canvas/UI. Which part of that is confusing?

Comment: If I do what you said I will end with lines on the top of all elements of Canvas/UI. What I need is to have the lines on the top of image (or any game-object) but at the same time under another game-object (buttons).

Comment: What I am trying right now is to put image in canvas1 and buttons in canvas2 and change canvas2 Plane Distance, and then the lines will be drawn over canvas1 and under canvas2

Comment: Your solution works good with 2 canvases.
But I have one last question: You said that you can use image or rawimage to do this.
actually I have an image and I need to draw lines on it, what is the best solution to draw on the image. Thanks!

Comment: My answer shows how to make LineRenderer appear on top of a Canvas element like you requested. Note that if you are using multiple canvas, you can modify the "Order In Layer"* variable on both Canvases and `LineRenderer` to determine which is on top or bottom.

Comment: If you last comment is asking about drawing lines directly to a sprite/texture, you may want to take a look at [this](https://github.com/betajaen/giraffe) and [this](https://bitbucket.org/ddreaper/unity-ui-extensions/wiki/Controls/UILineRenderer) for UI. Good luck.